# Clean iPhone cache after iOS 8.3

Tags: iphone, ios

I was a PhoneClean and PhoneExpander user but, after iOS 8.3 update, they (and similar apps) stopped working due to some modifications in iOS.

Now I start having too much cache on my phone but I don't want to remove and reinstall apps to clean their cache, is there a faster way to do that? (apps updated to support iOS 8.3 or iOS apps or other ways...)

I don't want to jailbreak.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8.3, Apple revoked the user's ability to access a downloaded app's files (Documents & Data). Further, third party apps don’t natively provide a way to delete their "Documents & Data". It's an inconvenient feature in the OS, yet it exists, even from the beta stages.

However, in an attempt to defend Apple, this could have been an extra security measure to prevent users from hacking apps. Another possibility is that the cleaning apps you mentioned are simply not up-to-date with the new OS.

Sadly, you will have to delete the app off of your iDevice, and reinstall it, to remove any app data. You can do this either from the iDevice itself, or using iTunes on a computer.

You *could* jailbreak your iDevice which would give you access to multiple cleaning tools, but a jailbreak *could* be difficult to keep up with. You also don't want to accidentally mess with something serious.

It's a sad but certain truth that apps must be removed and reinstalled. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it may help much, but I tried using an app called, [Battery Doctor](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/battery-doctor-must-have-battery/id615987910?mt=8). I just started using this app because I was annoyed with my storage mostly consists of "Other" files. 
I'm also PhoneExpander user and not a jailbreak lover ether! Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I saw this app times ago but I forgot his name! Does it work cleaning "Other"?   Times ago, I seem to remember, that in app's description there was a mention to cache cleaning function, now none...

Comment: The app has 5 tabs, the status, charge (i.e. shows the battery's health), memory boost (i.e. where it helps maximize the memory), junk (i.e. this does a clean up cache), and market, that one is not important. As for cleaning "Other," NOT that much, it just helps maintain the iPhone's life overall mostly. Sorry, it's the best app I can think of other than the ones that we use. However, the app is free, so doesn't hurt to check it out, I guess! :) Good luck, let me know if you find other solutions!

Comment: I tried it and it clean very softly (on 1,2 gb of useless cache, it clean 92mb;  for example 392mb of Spotify's cache weren't touched...), I'll wait if someone has better solutions...

Comment: Ahh... I figured that was the case. I'm sorry, I tried my best! I'll also wait too. This problem is quite annoying. Good luck to ya!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to jailbreak and use something like iCleaner.

https://ib-soft.net

Comment: I'm not a jailbreak lover...

Comment: Me neither, but this is the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm running iOS 8.4 and [iBrowse](https://www.ibrowseapp.com) has been functioning without jailbreaking all along.

I just visited their website and they even announced iOS 9 support!

Comment: Seems it works to navigate iPhone's directories but I can't see any cache cleaner function...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't have that functionality. I use it to clear my Videos app cache. They're under CloudAssets folder. If yours are something else, you might have to do some more inspection but it won't be that hard since the folder names are meaningful. Best of luck and be careful!

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve security, Apple made a huge action since iOS 8.3: in the document of About the security content of iOS 8.3, it's clearly pointed out the limitation of sandbox profile. Previously only writing was blocked in executable directory, but now Apple totally kills the app sandbox access. Thus, all the third party apps, which are based on accessing system files inside other apps, come to an overall standstill. I also use clean-up apps(iMyfone Umate), but it hasn't a similar situation like you, except for cleaning up third party apps data. So I think it doesn't stop working. Only when these clean-up apps access some special data on iOS 8.3 or later, they won't be permitted.

If you don't want to remove and reinstall apps or jailbreak, what you need to do is clean up cache and junk files by manual in settings.

Comment: I can't clean up cache in system's settings and 80% of apps hasn't a clean cache button...

Comment: It is true. Some apps don't support to clean up caches in settings.Oh, I used that tool which I mentioned and it goes well until now.

Comment: I'll try it. This http://www.imyfone.com/iphone-space-saver-mac/ , right?

Comment: Yes. Good luck. :) hope we can exchange experience

Comment: It promise to remove 5,70gb... 4,64gb of all my apps and 200mb of "Larger photos"... is it kidding?! Would be interesting to try the Temporary files cleaning to see if remove only useless files, but unlucky Temporary files cleaning isn't included in trial and 20$ to see "how it works" are too much...

Comment: Er...Actually, trial version has a limited feature. Removing some apps is not a good way, it is only for your reference. Temporary file clean-up and large file deletion are latest remarkable features, so maybe this is the reason why they are not in trail, but I have to admit that these functions helped me release more than 3.5 gb, I checked storage after using it.